# Why is an item displying at the very bottom of a django template/page?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, calendar

I cannot resolve the following;

I'm using django `calendar` module and I try to display it in a template like this. It is a very first shot with the calendar and what is happening I haven't seen before. The {{ calendar }} renders correctly-ish but it renders at the very bottom of the page regardless of what I do (positioning within the html file, wrapping in divs with positioning etc. Any idea why this might be happening?

calendar.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}

<div class="container background-style min-vh-100">
    <a href="{% url 'calendar' %}?{{ prev_month }}"> Previous Month </a><a href="{% url 'calendar' %}?{{ next_month }}"> Next Month </a>
{#    <div style="display: flex; height: 20px; width: 200px; background: white; border: red 6px solid"></div>#}
    {{ calendar }}

    <h3 class="first_heading">Vyberte si volný termín, který Vám vyhovuje</h3>
    <h4 style="text-align: center">Níže naleznete kalendář. Zde si vyberte volný slot, ve kterém byste si rád(a) domluvila konzultace</h4>
    <a href="{% url 'booking_step_1' %}" ><button class="button2">Další »</button></a>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

EDIT:
here is how the calendar is created in utils.py;

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from calendar import HTMLCalendar
from .models import Health_Session

class Calendar(HTMLCalendar):
    def __init__(self, year=None, month=None):
        self.year = year
        self.month = month
        super(Calendar, self).__init__()

    # formats a day as a td
    # filter events by day
    def formatday(self, day, events):
        events_per_day = events.filter(start_time__day=day)
        d = ''
        for event in events_per_day:
            d += f'<li> Konzultace {event.id}, {event.start_time}  </li>'

        if day != 0:
            return f"<td><span class='date'>{day}</span><ul> {d} </ul></td>"
        return '<td></td>'

    # formats a week as a tr
    def formatweek(self, theweek, events):
        week = ''
        for d, weekday in theweek:
            week += self.formatday(d, events)
        return f'<tr> {week} </tr>'

    # formats a month as a table
    # filter events by year and month
    def formatmonth(self, withyear=True):
        events = Health_Session.objects.filter(start_time__year=self.year, start_time__month=self.month)

        cal = f'<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="calendar">\n'
        cal += f'{self.formatmonthname(self.year, self.month, withyear=withyear)}\n'
        cal += f'{self.formatweekheader()}\n'
        for week in self.monthdays2calendar(self.year, self.month):
            cal += f'{self.formatweek(week, events)}\n'
        return cal
```

Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: First thing that sticks out is the `{#`.

Comment: that is just one line of a commented-out div with no efect

Comment: Please provide the minimal code required to reproduce the problem. The rendered HTML output would also be helpful.

Comment: I believe this is more generic problem, I mean why would something render at the very bottom instead of its place? under footer and so on which is part of base.html so far below where calendar's block content ends

Comment: That usually happens because of broken HTML or CSS.

Answer (score 2):

```
cal +=f'</table>'
return cal
```

You're missing a /table tag.

Comment: This was it!  However it was complicated by an inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation error when adding this line of code.  I'm using Atom.  I had to research further and add the code via notepad and then reopen it in Atom.  Thanks for the assist.

Comment: this is a solution! thanks for this great hint!